# join eloquent table with custom format response

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm just join 3 eloquent tables. it works but the response json format is not what I want. I need to customizing the format response so it will easy to read.

this is my join table code

```
$showPresensi = Event::join('presensis', 'presensis.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
            ->join('anggotas', 'presensis.anggota_id', '=', 'anggotas.id')
            ->where('presensis.event_id', 2)
            ->get(['events.*', 'anggotas.nama_lengkap','presensis.kehadiran']);
    return $this->ok($showPresensi, "Success");
```

and  this is my current response json

```
{
"message": "Success",
"success": true,
"code": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nama": "Event 2",
        "tanggal": "Sabtu, 12 Februari 2022",
        "permintaan_dari": "Yang bersangkutan",
        "hasil_kegiatan": "nothing",
        "created_at": "2022-02-12T21:53:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-12T21:53:14.000000Z",
        "nama_lengkap": "user 1",
        "kehadiran": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nama": "Event 2",
        "tanggal": "Sabtu, 12 Februari 2022",
        "permintaan_dari": "Yang bersangkutan",
        "hasil_kegiatan": "nothing",
        "created_at": "2022-02-12T21:53:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-12T21:53:14.000000Z",
        "nama_lengkap": "user 3",
        "kehadiran": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nama": "Event 2",
        "tanggal": "Sabtu, 12 Februari 2022",
        "permintaan_dari": "Yang bersangkutan",
        "hasil_kegiatan": "nothing",
        "created_at": "2022-02-12T21:53:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-12T21:53:14.000000Z",
        "nama_lengkap": "user 2",
        "kehadiran": "1"
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to column of **nama_lengkap** and **kehadiran** become an array so it will become like this:

```
{
  "message": "Success",
  "success": true,
  "code": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nama": "Event 2",
      "tanggal": "Sabtu, 12 Februari 2022",
      "permintaan_dari": "Yang bersangkutan",
      "hasil_kegiatan": "nothing",
      "created_at": "2022-02-12T21:53:14.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-02-12T21:53:14.000000Z",
      "presensi": [
        {
          "nama_lengkap": "user 1",
          "kehadiran": "0"
        },
        {
          "nama_lengkap": "user 3",
          "kehadiran": "0"
        },
        {
          "nama_lengkap": "user 2",
          "kehadiran": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

is there any solution for this? any clues are helps. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) with Eloquent.

Then you could do:

```
$showPresensi = Event::with('presensis', 'presensis.anggotas').find(2);
```

The structure should match more closely what you're going for. Then you could either modify the collection to get exactly what you want, or add [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to your models.